# Ajax XMLhttprequest Post to PHP script and Rotate Image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, rotation

I know where I have big problems but I can't seem to solve them. I am trying to rotate an image using PHP via Ajax. I just wand to rotate the image 90 degrees with each button press. Can someone please help. I know I am telling my PHP script to retrieve the $_POST['image'] variable but I'm not sending one which is why I am getting php errors. I know the php script works. I don't know if I can use the xhttp.open("GET") or not in my script either. I know there are other problems with my html and reloading the image in the  tag, too. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>

function rotateImage(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML =   this.responseText;
   }
};

xhttp.open("POST", "rotate.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xhttp.send("<?php echo $fileName; ?>");
}
</script>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
    
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $degree = 90;
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    // Rotate
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degree, 0);
    $image = imagejpeg($rotate, realpath($image), 100);
    //echo $image;
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
```

?>

And my HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg col-auto">
    <?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileName); ?>     
        <div class="mb-1" id="rotate"><img class="rounded img-fluid" src="<?php echo $fileName; ?>" alt="Your Profile Photo" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" /></div>
        <div class="text-center"><button onClick="rotateImage()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i> Rotate</button></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without understanding the intended strategy. 
Try asking yourself two questions (1) what does the PHP script send back to the client? (2) is `... .innerHTML = this.responseText` the correct thing to do with it?

Comment: okay well I figured this part out I think: 
xhttp.send("image="+<?php echo $fileName; ?>);

Comment: The image on the page just needs to be reloaded without reloading the page to reflect the rotated image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the question it is unknown where and how the initially declared `$filename` is derived or what the particular folder structure / server configuration is so the following perhaps need tweaks to suit your environment as my test site uses aliased folders outwith the site root... Anyway - the sending of a filename/filepath to PHP using Ajax( or the Fetch api as here ) is easy enough. The PHP script does what it is supposed to except that it does not return a value but the trick to forcing the browser to `"reload"` the image when the ajax request finishes is to append a cache busting timestamp.

Reputedly the `cache:'reload'` property that can be set on a `Fetch` request will ensure the image is not cached but I found this had no effect in this situation.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( 
        $_POST['filename'],
        $_POST['path'],
        $_POST['dir']
    )){
        ####################
        # emulate rotate.php
        ####################
        ob_clean();
        
        $image = sprintf('%s/%s', $_POST['path'], basename( $_POST['filename'] ) );
        $angle = $_POST['dir']=='clockwise' ? -90 : 90;
        
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $image );
        imagesetinterpolation( $source, IMG_MITCHELL );
        
        $rotate = imagerotate( $source, $angle, 0 );
        imagejpeg( $rotate, realpath( $image ), 100 );

        imagedestroy( $source );
        imagedestroy( $rotate );
        
        list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $image );
        
        $args=array(
            'filename'  =>  $_POST['filename'],
            'width'     =>  $width,
            'height'    =>  $height
        );
        
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $args ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class='row justify-content-center mb-3'>
            <div class='col-lg col-auto'>
                <?php
                
                    /*
                        $path here will be the full path and $filename
                        contains the web accessible path. As mentioned
                        my setup is complicated and relies upon aliased
                        folders outside site root.
                    */
                    $path=realpath( sprintf('%s/images/uploads', getcwd() ) );
                    $filename='images/uploads/abronsius.jpg';
                ?>     
                <div class='mb-1' id='rotate'>
                    <img class='rounded img-fluid' data-path='<?php echo $path;?>' src='<?php echo $filename; ?>' alt='Your Profile Photo' />
                </div>
                
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' data-dir='clockwise'>
                        <i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>Rotate Clockwise
                    </button>
                    
                    <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' data-dir='anticlockwise'>
                        <i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i>Rotate Anti-Clockwise
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <script>
            (function(){
                
                const d=document;
                const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
                const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
                
                qa('button.btn').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                    let img=q('img.img-fluid');
                    
                    /* set the payload to send in the request */
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.set('filename', img.src.split('?')[0] );
                        fd.set('path', img.dataset.path );
                        fd.set('dir', e.target.dataset.dir );
                    
                    let url=location.href;  //rotate.php
                    
                    /* set the request parameters */
                    let args={
                        body:fd,
                        mode:'same-origin',
                        method:'post',
                        cache:'reload', //no discernible effect
                        credentials:'same-origin'
                    };
                    /* create the request */
                    let oReq=new Request( url, args );
                    
                    /* send the request and process the response by reloading the image */
                    fetch( oReq )
                        .then( r=>r.json() )
                        .then( json=>{
                            img.src=json.filename +'?t='+( new Date() ).getTime();
                            img.width=json.width;
                            img.height=json.height;
                        })
                        .catch( err=>console.log(err) );
                }));
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Before]
[image: After-no hard-reload required]

Comment: The variable $fileName is the relative path to the image I am trying to rotate after it is processed  and uploaded through the form the user fills out on the previous page. the problem I am having is that after I process the image it seems to rotate CW 90 degrees when the photo was taken portrait orientation from an iPad and CCW 90 degrees when taken portrait orientation from an Android device.  The result is that the profile photo can be unpredictable in orientation after the upload. this looks like what I'm after. I'll give it a try. thanks. unless you have other suggestions?

Comment: I believe that is a commonly experienced phenomenon with iPhone/iPad pictures... there is a common approach to dealing with it I believe but cannot remember what it is. With the above you will likely need to analyse the console to see and respond to any error messages - PHP will grumble if the paths are incorrect  etc but once you have sorted the paths this should be ok - works fine here in test anyway. goodluck

Comment: It works buddy! Thank you so much!

Comment: you might possibly like to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: roger that. Thanks again.